# Directly access element of a structure

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, overloading

Is it possible to make a structure mimic one of its elements? Example:

```
struct example_struct
{
  double x[2];
  double operator[](int i){return x[i];};
}
struct example_struct var;
```

Now, assuming `var.x` has somehow been initialised, expressions like `std::cout<<var[1];` clearly work, but what should I do to make expressions like `var[1]=3;` work?

Comment: Make your return type `double&` and find a [solid C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/

Comment: `struct example_struct var;` is C. You don't need struct here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return a reference, not a copy in order for `var[1]=3` to work.

```
struct example_struct
{
   double x[2];
   double& operator[](int i) return x[i];};
}
```